# Incompatible Gems on M1 Macbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apple-m1

I've faced an issue when trying to run a console on my Ruby on Rails project. It gives me the following error:

```
/Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/msgpack.bundle' (no such file), '/usr/lib/msgpack.bundle' (no such file) - /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:5:in `require'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:45:in `rescue in with_gems'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:41:in `with_gems'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `require_relative'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:3:in `require_relative'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/scheduled_tweets/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
       from /Users/artemhb/scheduled_tweets/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
       from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
       from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
/Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/msgpack.bundle' (no such file), '/usr/lib/msgpack.bundle' (no such file) - /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:5:in `require'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:42:in `with_gems'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `require_relative'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:3:in `require_relative'
       from /Users/artemhb/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/artemhb/scheduled_tweets/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
       from /Users/artemhb/scheduled_tweets/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
       from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
       from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

A few Gems that seem not to work with an ARM architecture: mgspack and bootsnap. I was able to solve an issue with one Gem however – bcrypt by installing the right version of it `gem install bcrypt --platform arm-linux`. Does anyone know how would I prevent this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm on Apple M1 Pro, and have bootsnap (1.9.3) and msgpack (1.4.2) installed ok, for what it's worth. I notice that bootsnap is `require: false`, though `require `"bootsnap/setup"` is called in `config/boot.rb`

Comment: @DavidAldridge thank you, I will give this a try!

Comment: Can I know the status of this, I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall msgpack
2. Install unsupported version via gem installation

   `gem install msgpack -v 1.4.2`

   Then bundle will take this specific version
3. For all incompatible gems ,follow the same steps as 3.